# In what order does vim read ftplugin files, syntax files, and the .vimrc when `filetype plugin on` and `set syntax=filetype` are called?

Tags: vimrc, filetype, plugin-system

I've had some issues reconciling my `.vimrc` with files in `ftplugin` and `after/ftplugin`. In what order are they all read?

For example: When vim encounters the line `plugin filetype on` in a `.vimrc` file, is the filetype program read immediately, or after the rest of `.vimrc` executes? Further, am I correct in assuming that vim checks for a `.vim/ftplugin/filetype.vim` file before loading the "default" `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/filetype.vim` (only running the default file if no user version is found), then checks for files in `.vim/after/ftplugin`?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer, because it isn't a full answer, but you can call `:scriptnames` to see a list of every single file that has been sourced, and the order it was sourced in.

Comment: Does that list imply the files are read strictly sequentially? Like a plugin file will never be "cut" inside the `.vimrc` text?

Comment: `:h syntax-loading`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `filetype plugin on` is encountered in your vimrc, `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin.vim` is immediately executed. This creates an auto command which does the following:

```
exe 'runtime! ftplugin/' . name . '.vim ftplugin/' . name . '_*.vim ftplugin/' . name . '/*.vim'
```

This executes all matching files in each directory in `'runtimepath'`.

Note that auto commands are executed in the order in which they are defined,
so if you have the following in your vimrc:

```
au filetype php echoerr 'before'
filetype plugin on
au filetype php echoerr 'after'
```

And have this at the top of `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/php.vim`:

```
echoerr 'during'
```

Then you will see the errors `'before'`, `'during'`, `'after'` echoed in sequence when you edit a php file.